# Postgresql query output format

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two table

**component**

```
id    -    component_name     parent_id(self ref)
----------------------------------------
1      -   computer                 
2      -   cpu                   1
3      -   lcd
4      -   keyboard
```

**subcomponent**

```
id    -   name             ref_component
-------------------------------------
1     -  motherboard       2
2     -  ram               2
3     -  processor         2
```

Now when I pass computer id in where cause than my desire output should be following

```
computer
  -cpu
     -processor
     -motherboars
     -ram
  -lcd
  -keyboard
```

Comment: with spaces at the beginning?

Comment: How do you know that cpu is a "child" of "computer"? There is no parent/child information in your `component` table.

Comment: its space indicate intention. if possible than.

Comment: @ShyamSolanki - how many levels do you have?  ie - will you need some sort of tree-assembling query?  Otherwise you've simply reposted your earlier question.  Note that, as in the potential duplicate, actual formatting should be left to the program that actual displays the output.  Also... why do you have a separate `subcomponent` table?

Comment: level is not fix.. up to n level..

Comment: Why lcd and keyboard are children of computer? They have no parent_id. Also, if the level is infinity, you should have only one table (only the first), there is no need of the `subcomponent` table, it just make things hard (I can give a solution without it).

Answer (score 1):

If you have an infinity levels of subcomponents, than a better approach was to use only the `components` table. As it has a self-reference columns, it make pretty easy to use it with a [RECURSIVE query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html).

The following query will do the trick:

```
WITH RECURSIVE items AS (
   SELECT c.id, c.component_name, 1 AS level, array[c.component_name]::text[] AS path
   FROM component c
   WHERE c.parent_id IS NULL
   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.id, c.component_name, i.level + 1, array_append(i.path, c.component_name)
   FROM component c JOIN items i ON c.parent_id = i.id
)
SELECT repeat('|---', level-1) || component_name
FROM items
ORDER BY path;
```

The `repeat` function is just to make it easy to see direct on the database client, on a programming language you could use `level`, `id` and `parent_id` (or even just `path`) to control the output.

See the **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/363f4/4)** with this example.